# How to count messages for a user with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to count number of messages each user got. I have a users with user's detail `id, name` etc. I have created another table `users_msgs` where I have `id, msg_id, user_id`. I want to display count of messages each user got. what will be the best way to do it?

**The web application have more than 2000 users. so the script have to select all of them and count their messages. I think this is not the best solution.**

**I thinking of count rows for 1 user from `users_msgs` table as count and then querying the users table for user's name with his id from `users_msgs` table.**

I have tried selecting all users without any limit:

```
SELECT * FROM users
```

then iterating over the results like so:

```
<?php

  while ($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($users)) {
    $count = count_user_msgs($user['id']);
    echo "{$user['name']} messages: $count";
  }

?>
```

The `count_user_msgs` function looks like this:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) as msgs_count FROM users_msgs WHERE user_id = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($db);
if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $user_id);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
  $count = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)['msgs_count'];
  return $count;
}
return false;

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group by each user and get the count:

```
$sql = "SELECT user_id, name, count(user_id) as msgs_count from table group by (user_id, name)";

$result = $mysqli->query($query)

while ($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($users)) {
    $user_id = $users['user_id'];
    $msgs_count= $users['msgs_count'];
    $count[$user_id] = $msgs_count;
    echo "{$user['name']} messages: $msgs_count";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, You can get it in a single query...

```
SELECT u.name, count(m.user_id) message_count
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN users_messages m ON u.user_id=m.user_id
GROUP BY m.user_id, u.name
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to count the number of `msg_id`s per `user_id`, so you'll want to `GROUP BY user_id` and count `msg_id`, like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(msg_id) as msgs_count FROM user_msgs WHERE user_id = ? GROUP BY user_id";
```

The `GROUP BY` might not be necessary.

Comment: This is will get the count of message with user id. so I still have to iterate over all the users to get their ID.